# What components of spaCy Pipeline can be disabled so that the sentence tokenization can still work and the pipeline be faster?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to use the spaCy pipeline only for sentence tokenization as it's the best for my language but I want it to be as minimal as possible.

So far I figured I could get rid of tagger and ner components:

`nlp = spacy.load("pl_core_news_sm", disable=['tagger', 'ner'])`

I noticed that without `tok2vec` it doesn't work (which seems very odd).
I don't want to try all combinations because I'd surely miss something.

So does anyone know what components can be disabled so that the tokenization can still work and the pipeline be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the exact same sentence segmentation from `pl_core_news_sm` with the fewest components, enable only `tok2vec`+`parser`.

For faster sentence segmentation, disable everything that's enabled by default and then enable `senter`. For sentences with sentence-final punctuation, the performance is probably similar to the parser. If you don't have sentence-final punctuation, then the parser may perform better, but evaluate it for your task.

See: https://spacy.io/models/#design-modify